# VBS replace and write

Tags: vbscript, replace, readline

Start of that I'm not that good with VBS but trying to learn.
Right now I have some difficulties with writing replace to a text file.

What I want to do is to search for the text "VGML", when this is found check on same row if there is a "STML" if so, this should replaced with "    " to not mess up the positions in the file. And finally, if "VGML" is found without the "STML", the "VGML" should be removed.

I got so far when using echo I can see that the code does what I want, but writing to file mostly get me a empty file where the code removed everything.

Could anyone put me in the correct direction?

Here is the code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Script\RemoveSTML\testFiles\test.txt", ForReading)

strEMTY = "    "
strSTML = "STML"
strVGML = "VGML"

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
   strLine = objFile.ReadLine
   If InStr(strLine,strVGML)>0 Then
      If Instr(strLine,strSTML)>0 Then
         strLine = Replace(strLine, strSTML, strEMTY)
         wscript.Echo strLine
      Else
         strLine = Replace(strLine, strVGML, strEMTY)
         wscript.Echo strLine
      End If
   End If                                             
Loop
objFile.Close
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Script\RemoveSTML\testFiles\test.txt", ForWriting)
objFile.Write strLine
objFile.Close
Wscript.Echo "done"
```

Thanks for your help! For giving me a kick in the correct direction!

Comment: Since you're just getting started, here's a tip: always start your scripts with [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29) and get in the habit of explicitly declaring your variables using `Dim`.  This will almost certainly save you from trouble in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the loop, you read each line of the file and you write it into the variable `strLine`.
After that, you replace "SMTL"/"VGML", but after that, you're doing nothing with the content of `strLine` - you just replace it with the next line from the source file in the next loop.

Only at the end, you write `strLine` to the file once - but in that moment, `strLine` contains only the last line from the source file.

Solution: you can either write into the destination file **inside** the `Do...Loop` (but I'm not familiar with VBScript, so I don't know if/how to do this) or you can use a second string variable where you append `strLine` inside the loop but after the replacing...like this:

```
strFinal = strFinal & strLine
```

At the end, you write `strFinal` to the file, not `strLine`.

Comment: This put me more in the correct direction, not stuck on the same page at least, not working as I want just yet. But hopefully soon I can get it run as I want. Thanks for this help!

Comment: Would like to let you know that your input helped me solve this now! I just needed to add `strFinal = strFinal & strLine & vbCr & vbLf` now it flows perfectly, took me a weekend and one night. Thanks again for your help! See this as solved.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I forgot about the line breaks when I wrote this. I don't know if this also exists in VBScript, but in VBA (which I use a lot) you can also use `vbCrLf` instead of `vbCr & vbLf`.